# check variable with empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if this variable contains empty input field converted with parseInt? I have to store input val into a variable and I need to use parseInt. Please help.

```
var myinput = parseInt ($('input#day').val());

if (myinput.length < 1){
    $('<p>Empty field</p>').appendTo('#mydiv'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this way, since you're using jQuery:

```js
var input = $(this);

// This suffices
if (!input.val()) {
   // Empty
     $('#mydiv').append(input)
}

// However, if you insist on the use of parseInt, then try this
if (!parseInt(input.val())) {
   // Empty
     $('#mydiv').append(input)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The Code snippet shows error. Yes I have to use parseInt. I used this on this way bit it does not work: 
$("#day).on("blur", function(){
   days = parseInt ($('input#day').val());
   if (!parseInt(days.val())) {

      alert("empty field");
     }
     })

Comment: Try this: `$("#day).on("blur", function(){ days = parseInt ($(this).val()); if (!days) { alert("empty field"); } })`